# MATLAB: while loop with boolean value

Tags: matlab, while-loop, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

why my loop is not working , is there any syntax error.
here is my code :

```
v=false;

while ((i < N)&&(v==false))
         if (condition)
             v=true;
             i=i+1;
         else
             i=i+1;
         end
end
```

Comment: What are `condition`, `N` and the initial value of `i`?  You can also use `~v` instead of `v==false`.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

something like this works

```
i=0;
N=5;
while ((i < N)&&(v==false))
         if (false)
         v=true;
         i=i+1;
     else
         i=i+1;
     end
end
```

you either have a wrong condition inside the if or you haven't initialized i and N

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is:

```
i=0;
N=10;
while i<N
    if condition_to_stop
         break;
    end
    i = i+1;
end
```